# UIBarButtonItem Not Shown Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am making a simple navigation controller and I want to add a right bar button item programmatically but I cannot get it shown. The color becomes red and the name shows up as "My App" but no add button for some reason.

Any ideas?

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController)
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = false
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
nav.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "My App"
nav.navigationBar.textColor = UIColor.white        
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addStuff))
add.tintColor = UIColor.white
nav.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are adding the button to the wrong `navigationItem`. The nav bar shows the `navigationItem` of the top-most view controller so you need to add the button to the view controller's `navigationItem`.

You should also set the view controller's title, not the nav bar's title.

```
myViewController.title = "My App"
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController)
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
nav.navigationBar.textColor = UIColor.white        
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addStuff))
add.tintColor = UIColor.white
myViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add
```